# How to turn off snippets in Atom?

Tags: configuration, code-snippets, atom-editor

I've recently started using [Atom](https://atom.io/). One problem I've run into is that there are too many / ambiguous snippets defined for Ruby. This makes tab completion worse, as you sometimes get a bit of irrelevant code instead of the name you wanted. I'm wondering how to turn off a specific snippet from the "Language Ruby" package, or failing that turning off all snippets. Preferably without disabling the Ruby package entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there's currently no built-in feature for this kind of thing.

Until some filter feature is added to the snippets package, the only way to access the snippets is to monkey-patch the package from your init script.

For instance something like that will allow you to filter the snippets returned for a given editor at runtime:

```
# we need a reference to the snippets package
snippetsPackage = require(atom.packages.getLoadedPackage('snippets').path)

# we need a reference to the original method we'll monkey patch
__oldGetSnippets = snippetsPackage.getSnippets

snippetsPackage.getSnippets = (editor) ->
  snippets = __oldGetSnippets.call(this, editor)

  # we're only concerned by ruby files
  return snippets unless editor.getGrammar().scopeName is 'source.ruby'

  # snippets is an object where keys are the snippets's prefixes and the values
  # the snippets objects
  console.log snippets

  newSnippets = {}
  excludedPrefixes = ['your','prefixes','exclusion','list']

  for prefix, snippet of snippets
    newSippets[prefix] = snippet unless prefix in excludedPrefixes   

  newSnippets
```

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore. `Cannot find module '/usr/share/atom/resources/app.asar/node_modules/snippets'`

Answer (score 0):

From [atom discussion board](https://discuss.atom.io/t/snippets-are-killing-me/39954/3):

> There are two packages: `snippets` and `autocomplete-snippets` that you can disable from the settings-view packages tab. `autocomplete-snippets` is the package that adds snippets to the autocomplete+ suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I too suffer from snippet overload in Atom. While I couldn't find a way to turn snippets off in the settings, I found a workable solutions for now.

In the custom snippets file (Mac menu: Atom > Snippets...), prepend your snippets' prefix property with some letter. This way they're always sorted to the top of the autocomplete list. I chose the letters 'aa'.

Ember snippet example:

```
"Dirk's Label & Input":
    'prefix': 'aaLabel & Input'
    'body': """
        <label>
            $1
            <Input
                @type='text'
                @value={{this.$2}}
            />
        </label>
    """
```

Now when I type aa all my snippets show first ... ;-)