# Managing preinstalled snippets in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I've installed Atom editor, which comes with snippets `legal` and `lorem` (they are suggested every time I type " l", which is... well, redundant). I have 2 questions.

1. How to turn them off (and manage installed snippets in general)?
2. How to change their keybindings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off snippets in Atom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989997/how-to-turn-off-snippets-in-atom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question was about the two preinstalled snippets, so it wasn't a duplicate, and has a specific, easy answer that I'll give myself:

1. Ctr-, > Packages > language-text > Disable.
2. One way to change `legal` and `lorem` keybindings is to play w/ Settings > Packages > autocomplete-plus > Settings (e.g. w/ "Use strict.." and "Minimum word length"). There may be other ways under Ctr-, > Packages > language-text (haven't looked at it recently, as I was only interested in disabling it).

Answer (score 0):

- To manage your snippets, [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26060489/3711562)
- You could use [keybinding-cheatsheet](https://github.com/jkasky/atom-keybinding-cheatsheet) , [Second Link](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-cheatsheet) package for Atom to manage your keybindings, quickly view and filter atom keybindings